# Retrofit responses are delayed to full ConnectionTimeout of OkHttpClient

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I met a strange issue: after switching my app to use a new API all responses to API requests arrive after exactly the connection timeout i set in the OkHttpClient.Builder().

The backend server has a similar setup as the one i used before.
When i do the request from another client (postman, browser (even on the same phone)) there is no such a delay.

And when i route the traffic through a local Charles proxy then the request also performs normal.

I have currently no idea what's going on here.

API calls are done with

- retrofit2 2.9
- okhttp 4.11.0
- rxjava2 2.0.1

On a Pixel6 API 34 but happens on all devices

RESOLVED:

- See my comment about what caused the issue

Comment: Looks like i found the cause for the strange API Request behavior:
Turned out that the DNS entry for the URL had a faulty IPv6 address.
That caused the App to first run into the connection timeout when trying the IPv6 address.
Then it tried the IPv4 address which was correct.
Using a Proxy in between caused the app to just use the IPv4 address. Not sure why the Proxy prevented the delivery of the IPv6 address.

Comment: Additionally: That all happened in the underlying java.net layer. So it was independent of retrofit, okhttp, ktor, etc...